# Dataflow Mysql to Bigquery: Connection refused

Tags: mysql, jdbc, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

I am trying to ingest data from on-premise Mysql to Bigquery via Dataflow job, but it's failing to connect and fetch data. Has anyone come across similar issue?

This is the code I used

> gcloud dataflow jobs run mariadb_to_bigquery --gcs-location
>   gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Jdbc_to_BigQuery
>   --parameters=driverJars=gs://xxxxxx-xxxxx/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar,driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,connectionURL='jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/classicmodels?user=root&password=xxxxx',query='select
>   * from customers',outputTable=xxxxxx-xxxxx-******:ds010.customers,bigQueryLoadingTemporaryDirectory=gs://xxxxxx-xxxxx-******/my-files/temp-dir

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.beam.sdk.util.UserCodeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:817)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:204)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:155)
    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:65)
    ... 41 more

Thanks,
Srikanth
```

Comment: Are you sure you opened the proper ports wherever the MySQL db is located? Can you connect to it from outside the network that it's on? Have you granted the right permissions in the db for the IP that the dataflow job is coming from? (Given '%' permissions, and/or figured out what the IP is and whitelisted it specifically for Dataflow)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: A teammate of mine has highly recommended using the VPC network approach, since exposing the external mySQL endpoint puts the DB at risk of DDOS and brute force login attacks.

Since the Dataflow job runs on a GCE VM instance, it is not on the same machine as the JDBC endpoint which you use localhost/127.0.0.1 to connect to.

**Private IP over VPC network method**

1. Setup [a VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc), and use a private IP on the VPC network to connect to the JDBC instance, Instead of using the external IP address of your JDBC instance on a separate network. See: [VPC Network Peering](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering) or [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview).
2. You will likely need  [a firewall rule as well](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/how-to/configuring-firewall-rules), to allow traffic on your peer network with the GCP network.
3. Specify the --network name parameter when you launch the template.

> ```
> gcloud dataflow jobs run <job_name> --gcs-location <template_location>
> --parameters=network=<my_network>,param2=<value>,...
> ```

**External IP method** (Not recommended due to DDOS and brute force risk) You'll need to provide an external IP address instead and:

1. [create a custom network](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/networks/create) and give it a name.
2. [Define a firewall rule to allow egress TCP connections to your specific port on an external host](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls#example_3_allow_egress_tcp_connections_to_port_443_of_an_external_host), for the dataflow VM tag.

> ```
> gcloud compute firewall-rules create vm1-allow-egress-tcp-port3306-to-192-0-2-5 \
>     --network my-network \
>     --action allow \
>     --direction egress \
>     --rules tcp:3306 \
>     --destination-ranges 192.0.2.5/32 \
>     --priority 70 \
>     --target-tags dataflow
> ```

3. Specify the --network name parameter when you launch the template.

> ```
> gcloud dataflow jobs run <job_name> --gcs-location <template_location>
> --parameters=network=<my_network>,param2=<value>,...
> ```

You may want to use a [subnet calculator](https://mxtoolbox.com/subnetcalculator.aspx) to calculate the destination ranges properly

4. You may similarly need to configure your mySQL instance or network to allow this connection.

Also, it may be simpler to create a VM on the same network as your dataflow instances, ssh and and try to test jdbc connectivity with a small JDBC java program, prior to running a whole dataflow program. To troubleshoot faster.